# Most efficient way to request data and write the response to a file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, csv, python-requests

The problem I'm working on is finding the lat, long coordinate pairs for lots of addresses (like First St @ Second Ave) stored in an Excel file, and writing the new data to a CSV file. To actually convert the addresses to lat, long pairs, I used the ArcGIS REST API Geocode service (https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?)

I created a function for this, but it takes around 30 minutes to run through roughly 1600 rows of data. I'm sure it could be done faster, but I'm not sure where I could make improvements.

Here's the function I created. It references two helper functions: one to set the parameters for the request and another for writing a formatted response to a file.

```
url = "https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?"
params = {'f':'pjson','outFields':'Addr_type','forStorage':'false','City':'Oakville','Region':'ON'}
path = EXCEL_FILE_PATH

import pandas as pd
import requests
df = pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name="line_pts",usecols="A",dtype=str)

def writeToFile(path,data):
    with open(path,"a",newline="") as outFile:
      writer = csv.writer(outFile,dialect='excel')
          writer.writerow(data)

def setParams(val):
        params['Address'] = val
        return params

def search(query,savePath):
    import requests
    nonlocated = []
  
    for q in query:
        setParams(q)
        data = requests.get(url,params).json()
        data_dict = data.get('candidates')[0]

        if data_dict.get('score') >= 95:
            cols = ["Address","Type","Lat","Long"]
            dat = [data_dict.get('address'),data_dict.get('attributes').get('Addr_type'),data_dict.get('location').get('y'),data_dict.get('location').get('x')]
            writeToFile(savePath,dat)
        else:
            nonlocated.append(q)

    with open(r"C:\Users\PC\Documents\missing.txt","w") as missing:
        missing.write('Missed/Non-located places'  + "\n")
        for elem in nonlocated:
            missing.write(str(elem) + "\n")
                    
    print(f"{savePath} was written successfully. % missing data = {len(nonlocated)/len(df['DATA'])*100}")
        

search(df["DATA"],"INPUT-PATH")
```

The way I set up my logic, it seems the main inefficiency is that each request has to be fulfilled first before a single record is written to a file. Maybe there's a way to do both tasks in parallel, but I can't even think what the program logic would look like in that case.

Comment: you should add a caching layer

Comment: Can you use the [Batch geocoding](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/mapping-apis-and-services/geocoding/batch-geocoding/) REST service?

Answer (score 1):

using a thread pool with a requests session I was able to pull 1600 `'First St @ Second Ave'` in about 8 minutes.  obviously may vary with your list.

I like `imap_unordered` because the results are "as completed".  if the order matters then use `imap`.

original run I used `Pool()` which defaults to cpu count (16 on my desktop), but rather quickly got a json error.  reduced the number to `Pool(8)` and it ran fine.  so maybe there is some rate or connection limiting AND I did not take the time to investigate.

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from pprint import pp
import csv, requests


timeout = 10
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
DATA = ['First St @ Second Ave'] * 1600


def worker(val):
    url = 'https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?'
    params = {
        'f': 'pjson',
        'outFields': 'Addr_type',
        'forStorage': 'false',
        'City': 'Oakville',
        'Region': 'ON',
        'Address': val
    }

    try:
        data = session.get(url, params=params, timeout=timeout).json()
        return (val, data)
    except Exception as e:
        pp([type(e), e, val])
        return (val, 'missing data')


def search(query, savePath):
    with Pool(8) as pool, open(savePath, 'w', newline='') as outFile:
        query_len = len(query)
        nonlocated = []
        writer = csv.writer(outFile, dialect='excel')
        writer.writerow(['Address', 'Type', 'Lat', 'Long'])
        
        threads = enumerate(pool.imap_unordered(worker, query), 1)
        for i, (val, result) in threads:
            print(f'result {i} of {query_len}')
            if 'missing data' in result:
                nonlocated.append(val)
            else:
                data_dict = result.get('candidates')[0]
                if data_dict.get('score') >= 95:
                    dat = [
                        data_dict.get('address'),
                        data_dict.get('attributes').get('Addr_type'),
                        data_dict.get('location').get('y'),
                        data_dict.get('location').get('x'),
                    ]
                    writer.writerow(dat)
                else:
                    nonlocated.append(val)
    pool.join()
    
    with open('missing.txt', 'w') as missing:
        for elem in nonlocated: print(elem, file=missing)
    
    print(f'{savePath} was written successfully. % missing data = {len(nonlocated) / query_len * 100}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # search(df['DATA'],'INPUT-PATH')
    search(DATA, 'INPUT-PATH')
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply! Didn't even consider going about it this way, so appreciate the suggestion.